# Вывод списка статей авторов, на которых пользователь подписан

Tags: mysql

```
$podpiska = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `podpiska` where `id_user`=".$user['id'].""));
$count = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `articles` WHERE `moderation`="1" AND `pobeda`="0" AND `id_user`='.$podpiska['user_id'].''), 0);
if($count>0) 
{ 
$req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `moderation`='1' AND `pobeda`='0' AND `id_user`=".$podpiska['user_id']." ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
```

Нужно вывести список статей авторов, на которых пользователь подписался.

---

Таблица подписки имеет такой вид

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `podpiska` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`login_user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`user_login` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8;
```

Все вышенаписанное не работает. Выводятся статьи первого пользователя на которого человек подписался.

Comment: Если я верно понимаю, то в $podpiska Вы получаете список всех авторов на которых пользователь подписан.  Вам нужно в цикле перебирать всех авторов и собрать запрос такого плана:  

    SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `moderation`='1' AND `pobeda`='0' AND (`id_user`=vasja or id_user=petja or id_user=Nicolas ...) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ...
У Вас же в запрос попадает только один автор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если $podpiska больше нигде не нужна, все это можно заменить одним SQL запросом с вложенным select:

```
$req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `moderation`='1' AND `pobeda`='0' AND `id_user` IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `podpiska` WHERE `id_user`=".$user['id'].") ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message);
```

или, как рекомендует mysql, просто объединить таблицы:

```
$req = mysql_query("SELECT articles.* FROM `articles`, `podpiska` WHERE `articles.moderation`='1' AND `articles.pobeda`='0' AND `articles.id_user`=`podpiska.user_id` ORDER BY `articles.id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.
Только вот интересно за какой промежуток времени выведется 20 статей из БД и каждая размеров в 50к символов?

Comment: В php это все попадет очень быстро. Т.к. все происходит на sql-сервере и одним запросом.

Comment: В среднем одна статья у меня загружалась за 0.03 секунды.